# How can I check to see if a URL exists or not?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a Discord bot that will automatically post a message when a new chapter of a manga is posted. I have never done JavaScript before, and I have no idea what code one would use to do that. The URL ends in "/en/0/[Chapter Number]", and nothing else in the entire URL changes, so all the bot would have to do is check one number above the one posted, then when that link doesn't lead to a 404 anymore it posts the message on Discord and updates the chapter number it's checking. Any help you can give is appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I am using Node.js and Visual Studio Code, if that matters

Comment: Show the code for how you're getting the messages now.  Also, take a look at Regular Expressions.  Looks like you'll need something like `message.match(/\/en\/0\/([0-9]+/)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Node's [https](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html) built-in module to determine the status code of the page. If the status code is `200`, you would know the page exists. You could also check for other status codes (`404`, like you mentioned) that you see fit.

```js
const https = require('https')

https.get('https://discordapp.com/', res => {
    if(res.statusCode === 200) {
        console.log('Page exists!')
    }
})
```

Comment: Op is on node. `fetch` is not available by default.

Comment: @KevinPeña Good catch! Thanks

Comment: After looking at this and a few other pages about similar things I've now got it properly working! Now all I need to do is the other parts, so I guess it's actually time to learn the basics of JavaScript

Comment: @Jokaleth Good going! It's a language worth knowing imo. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a fast way in most situations, and you agree
'**unexist ≈ unexist or not public or HEAD request disallowed**', try this.

```
fetch(url, {method: 'HEAD'})
    .then(res => {
        if (res.status === 200) {
            ... // exist
            return;
        }
        ... // unexist
    })
    .catch(err => {
        ... // unexist
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to make a request to the url in order to check the response code. If you are working on a discord bot, you are probably using node, in that case you want to pick a request library and look up the documentation for using it:

Here are some of them:

- [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)
- [request](https://github.com/request/request)
- [node-fetch](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch)
- [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent)